# Time is not in the list yii framework error

Tags: php, yii

I have problem with *yii* framework. When I pick the for ins.:

```
20.01.2017 00:57
```

It gives an error that is

> Time is not in the list.

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <label>Starting Date and Time:  <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <?php
    $this->widget('ext.timepicker.EJuiDateTimePicker',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'attribute'=>'time',
        'language'=>'ru',
        'options'=>array(
            'timeFormat' => 'hh:mm',
            'changeMonth' => false,
            'changeYear' => false,
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'class'=>'rl-text',
            'autocomplete'=>'off',
        ),
    ));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'time'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your validation rules for this field.

Comment: exactly i am sorry what you mean?